# jQuery onChange event not working on mobile browsers

Tags: jquery, mobile, onchange

I have a dropdown menu with a list of options and I need to capture when the option is changed so that I may fire off a few funcitons.

The below code works perfectly on desktop browsers (tested in FF, Chrome and IE), but on mobile browsers the event is not captured (tested on HTC One M8 and Samsung Galaxy Tab 4, both with Chrome, as well as iPhone 6 with Safari).

Is anyone able to tell me why this does not work on mobile browsers, and more importantly, how I can make it work?

```
$('select.user-station', '#user-station').on('change', function(){
    { code goes here }
});
```

Comment: How/when do you bind this event? Maybe try delegating it even i'm not sure then why it is working on desktop device. BTW, you forgot to explain what do you mean by 'not working'? Maybe there is no click event bound for mobile device but as i've no idea what is `t.modalSidbarOpen`, i can only guessing...

Comment: BTW, how do you debug it? Is the change event fired or not? Etc...

Comment: @A.Wolff - Ignore the code bound to the event (removed from the question), it's the event itself that is not working (not being captured) on mobile.